# Application linking 2 versions of same library due to dependencies

Tags: cmake, libpng, ldd

I'm having problems with a library (libpng) which my application is dynamically linking on Linux.

The libpng version I'm using is libpng15. Since my application is also linking DI-GUY, which is linking libpng3, these 2 version clash. With "clash" I mean that the linker (ldd) picks the libpng3 instead of libpng15.

If I look at the ldd output, both libpng15 and libpng3 are listed. The order is the following:

```
    libpng.so.3 => ../lib/libpng.so.3 (0x00007f4bccdff000)
    libpng15.so.15 => ../lib/libpng15.so.15 (0x00007f4bc5d1b000)
```

In CMake, I make sure I link against 15 specifically:

```
add_library(PNG::Shared SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(PNG::Shared PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libpng15.so.15.4.0
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES z
)
```

From my understanding, the application should take libpng15, but since libpng.so.3 is further up in the ldd than the 15 version, the linker picks the libpng.so.3 instead.

How can I please force my application to use the libpng15.so.15, and the DI-GUY lib will use the libpng.so.3. Since I cannot recompile DI-GUY, I'm stuck with libpng.so.3 being also linked, but it should not get confused with the 15 version...

What I don't understand is why the libpng.so.3 is even considered since I explicitly link against libpng15.so.15.4.0

Comment: `With "clash" I mean that the linker (ldd) picks the libpng3 instead of libpng15.` - No, the linker correctly separates `libpng.so.3` and `libpng15.so.15` even when they are linked into the same executable. The problem is that these two library versions will likely have the **same symbols** (functions, variable), so the wrong symbol can be choosed at runtime. This is why linking with two versions of the same library should be avoided at any cost. Otherwise you could get sudden crashes.

Comment: My application is complaining at the start, that I compiled with libpng15.so.15 but running with libpng.so.3 so it does know that it should use the libpng15.so.15. Are you suggesting that if there would be a completely different lib "X" which is linked first, and has the same symbols as libpng, then X would be taken instead of libpng? This would be a disaster in my opinion, or is it only for the same libraries with different versions? If yes, how does the linker know that 2 libs are the same just a different version, and not just accidentally have the same symbols?

Comment: "My application is complaining at the start, that I compiled with libpng15.so.15 but running with libpng.so.3 so it does know that it should use the libpng15.so.15." - It seems that your application uses some libpng function which requests the version of the library. But the linker resolves libpng3 function to libpng15 (or vice versa). "how does the linker know that 2 libs are the same just a different version" - The linker sees `libpng.so.3` and `libpng15.so.15`: different names - different libraries. It doesn't treat them as same library but with different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right solution was to make the library, which is linking libpng3, link it in private mode:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PUBLIC 
    VigFramework
    PedestriansBDI_Base
    DIGUY::GraphicsApi
    DIGUY::Main
    DIGUYDevil::Main
    TBB::Main2
    Qt4::QtCore
    Qt4::QtSql
    Qt4::QtGui
    Qt4::QtXml
    Qt4::QtNetwork
    Tiff::Main
)

target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PRIVATE 
    PNG3::Shared #required for DIGUY
)
```

This will guarantee that the main application links with libpng15 and does not get polluted by libpng3 from the other libraries.